# ¿Como sumar los valores de los checkbox generados dinamicamente, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día. Actualmente genero una lista dinamicamente en la cual cada registro tiene su checkbox, estoy intentando ir sumando el valor de la clase `cod_cupon`

```
var cupones_bienvenida = $('#cupones_bienvenida');
                        var tipoCupon ='';

                        $.each(response.data, function (i) {
                            if (response.data[i].Tipo_cupon == 1){
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón de 60%";
                            }
                            else if(response.data[i].Tipo_cupon == 2){
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón de 80%";
                            }
                            else{
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón de 100%";
                            }


                              $('<tr class="cupones"/>')
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td')
                                        .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content').text(response.data[i].Nombre)))
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(tipoCupon))
                                    .append('<div class="cod_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Identificador + '</div>')
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
                                                .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                                            .append('<input type="checkbox" name="cupon_check" class="cupon_check" value="' + response.data[i].Identificador + '"/>')
                                                            .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                                    .appendTo(cupones_bienvenida);
```

De la siguiente forma realizo el contador al selecionar el checkbox, pero cuando deselecciono el checkbox no lo va restando, 
es decir si llevo dos checkbox seleccionado el resultado debe ser 2, pero si deselecciono 1, ya solo me quedaria 1 checkbox seleccionado por lo tanto el valor me tendria que imprimir 1.

```
var total = 0;
    $('#cupones_bienvenida').on('click','.cupon_check', function(e){
        console.log("SELECIONO checkbox");
        total++;
        console.log(total);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con este código

```
var total = 0;
    $('#cupones_bienvenida').on('click','.cupon_check', function(e){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            total++;
        }
        else{
            total--;
        }
        console.log(total);
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado esa parte y para obtener el valor de la clase cod_cupon, como seria?

Comment: puede ser de la siguiente manera dentro del evento onclick el que acabamos de resolver agregas var valor=$(this).parents("tr").find('.cod_cupon').html();